# init premount script error from dropbear

Tags: boot, init

I get the following error at early boot stage:

```
ipconfig: eth0: SIOCGIFINDEX: No such device
ipconfig: no devices to configure
/scripts/init-premount/dropbear: .: line 32: can't open /tmp/net-eth0.conf
```

I have uninstalled/purged dropbear, but I still get the error. As I had the complete tar.bz backup of my system taken soon after the installation, when I restored it, the error didn't show up. But when the system got a kernel update, again the same problem occurred. I am using Ubuntu 10.04 desktop edition on Asus Eeepc 1005px (Atom N450).

Edit 1:
There were no scripts in the `/scripts/init-premount/` directory.
There was a dropbear directory in the `/initramfs-tools/etc/` directory. I removed it and did: `sudo update-initramfs -u` But again that dropbear directory appeared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is a leftover `dropbear` script in `/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-premount/` you can try to remove it, followed by running `sudo update-initramfs`, and see if that helps.

Comment: Also check `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/` and subdirectories for mentions of dropbear.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same system behaviour as originally posted, only with Kernel 2.6.32-31. With 2.6.32-30 there were no messages while booting. I removed all dropbear scripts carefully but the error messages with Kernel 2.6.32-31 persisted. Very strange kind of stuff.

But forgot `sudo update-initramfs -u`
Thats it for complete deinstallation of dropbear.

Comment: Welcome to AU - from your wording we cannot be sure that this is a working solution. Please specify your answer.