# How to do a clean reinstall of initramfs

Tags: 10.10, boot, init

I was getting the error mentioned [in this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7675/init-premount-script-error) on Ubuntu 10.04. I upgraded to Ubuntu 10.10 through software update and again I'm getting this error.

```
mount: mounts none on /dev/pts failed: Device
```

Here is the boot log:

```
IP-Config: no response after 4 secs - giving up
/scripts/init-premount/dropbear: line 32: ipconfig: not found
/scripts/init-premount/dropbear: line 32: ipconfig: not found
/scripts/init-premount/dropbear: line 32: ipconfig: not found
/scripts/init-premount/dropbear: line 32: ipconfig: not found
/scripts/init-premount/dropbear: line 32: ipconfig: not found
/scripts/init-premount/dropbear: line 32: ipconfig: not found
/scripts/init-premount/dropbear: line 32: ipconfig: not found
/scripts/init-premount/dropbear: .: line 32: can't open '/tmp/net-*.conf'
fsck from util-linux-ng 2.17.2
```

I had purged dropbear, and it looks like some scripts are still remaining. Is it possible to do a clean re-install of initramfs?

EDIT 1:
`sudo update-initramfs -u` doesn't solve the issue. Also `sudo update-initramfs -c -k all` also doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Simple as. Shouldn't be able to hurt anything.

On another note, you should ask whoever packages dropbear to add that to their `postrm` script.

Answer (score 1):

With this problem, I did a complete removal of `dropbear`.  It seems that the hooks into `initramfs` are left behind.

> sudo apt-get remove --purge dropbear
>
> sudo apt-get clean

(clean to remove log-files and other temp stuff)

Issue the

> sudo update-initramfs -u

to ensure that the `initramfs` is reconfigured afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the dropbear issue.

I did the following:

1. I removed all dropbear related files by using the command:  `sudo find / -name dropbear* -exec rm -ri {} \;`
2. Then I did `sudo update-initramfs -c -k all`
3. Now only this error remains `mount: mounts none on /dev/pts failed: Device` It looks like there is an obsolete mount entry created by dropbear in the config files which get executed in pre-init stages. If some one could figure out that config file, I would be able to solve the whole issue.

Comment: do you check your /etc/fstab ?

Comment: Yes I did. There is no entry for /dev/pts in fstab.