# Many errors while removing KDE and Gnome

Tags: 16.04, gnome, kde

Let me begin what did I do first,
At first, I install gnome desktop environment in my Ubuntu 16.04, but then I install KDE plasma using

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

And then removed gnome using [this site](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7675...y-de-ubuntu-16) the first answer from the above site, but I cannot reinstall:
ubuntu unity with the command;

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
```

The error showing by the terminal is this:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    ubuntu-desktop : Depends: checkbox-gui but it is not going to be installed
    Recommends: python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat but it is not going to be installed
    Recommends: qt-at-spi but it is not going to be installed
    Recommends: sni-qt but it is not going to be installed
    Recommends: unity-webapps-common but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have removed KDE using synaptic and also tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1402...r-adding-a-ppa), both the solutions. But still the font are not like the previous, and while opening the Ubuntu I do not get the typical Ubuntu symbol, but the Gnome symbol, when booting into Ubuntu.

Edit:
While installing checkbox-gui;

```
sudo apt-get install checkbox-gui
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

N.B.:I have a dual boot with Windows 7

Comment: You probably have unfinished installation or stalled installation. Try doing a "dpkg --configure -a" first, then delete the lock file if it is still there.

Comment: If you're new to Linux, I suggest you exhaustively test various distros by means of Live USBs. Decide which one you really like and then backup your data and do a clean install of your choice. Mixing desktop environments *can* have consequences.

Comment: How  to delete the lock files?

Comment: I have already done "dpkg --configure -a", but still i could not install anything.